# Trouble accessing array return types

Tags: php

I'm trying to access my array values by calling them from another script.

I construct an array from my `countryConfig.xml` file. `var_dump` confirms that the values have been added successfully.

countryConfig.php

```
<?php
$configFile = 'countryConfig.xml';

function getCountryConfig($configFile) {

    $xml = new SimpleXmlElement(file_get_contents("countryConfig.xml"));

    $countries = array();

    $countryId = (string)($xml->city[0]->id);
    array_push($countries, $countryId);
    $countryId = (string)($xml->city[1]->id);
    array_push($countries, $countryId);

//    var_dump($countries); 

    return array (
        $countryId[0],
        $countryId[1]
     ); 
}
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
require 'includes/countryConfig.php';

$pageContent = 'The countries are' . $countryId[0] . ' and ' . $countryId[1];
?>
```

No results are displayed.  Any ideas where I'm going wrong?  I'm intending to print out the countries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second code block should be something like:

```
<?php
require 'includes/countryConfig.php';
$countryId = getCountryConfig('countryConfig.xml');
$pageContent = 'The countries are ' . $countryId[0] . ' and ' . $countryId[1];
echo $pageContent;
```

**Edit:** On a second view, your first code block seems to be incorrect as well. You should `return $countries`

Comment: With the above and the following  `return array (
        $cities[0],
        $cities[1]
);` I return Array Array...?

Comment: There is no `$cities` variable in your code. `return array($countries[0], $countries[1])` in your example is the same as `return $countries`

Comment: Excuse the `$cities` typo. Still returns Array, Array using `return $countries`. Just want to print the value at index 0, then index 1.